# Допускается ли в тексте писать обращение к группе лиц с большой буквы?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Примеры выражений: Это была первоклассная работа, Команда/Группа. Очень хорошо, Команда. Все зависит только от вас, Группа.

Comment: Что вы хотите этим показать?

Comment: Ну, в смысле, можно ли писать так или нужно писать всегда строчными слово "команда"? Есть ли какая-то зависимость в написании, когда можно использовать строчные или заглавные буквы?

Comment: Есть зависимость - в начале предложения заглавная буква, в середине - строчная.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Почти любое слово в определенном контексте можно писать с прописной. Примеры: *Она не зря положила жизнь, чтобы ее сын стал Человеком с большой буквы. [Эльдар Рязанов. Подведенные итоги (2000)] *   *У нас сегодня была Команда с большой буквы. [Домрачев В.. Армейский переворот. Уступая в третьем периоде 2:4, ЦСКА не только сравнял счет, но и выиграл по буллитам // Советский спорт, 2010.12.25] *

Answer (score 1):

Если обращение *адресуется* группе лиц, то начинаться оно должно со строчной буквы.